# Get cookie from AJAX repsonse

Tags: ajax, jquery, cookies, xmlhttprequest

I'm writing a chrome extension that uses AJAX to talk to a server. I want to read the `KEY` in `set-cookie` from AJAX response, but I cannot find a way to do this.

I have tried `document.cookie` and `xhr.getAllResponseHeaders()`

```
$.get(myURL,
      function (output, status, xhr) {
          console.log(document.cookie); //empty
          console.log(xhr.getAllResponseHeaders()); 
          //Only Connection and Content-Type shows
      }
);
```

The raw response header is:

```
Connection:Close
Content-Type:text/html
Set-Cookie:KEY=DFDSFDCB; PATH=/;
```

I know that according to spec, `getAllResponseHeaders()` is supposed to filter out `set-cookie` field. Is there any workaround?

Comment: What are you trying to read? If you want the "value from an AJAX response", that is usually what the server output -- the `output` variable in your callback. If you're trying to read the cookies, check out `document.cookie` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.cookie. I am not clear what you're after here.

Comment: If you want the cookie values, check out that MDN documentation page. They have a small cross-browser script to parse the cookies.